# Is my proof correct? Convergence of linear functions in normed space

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Suppose $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of linear transformations in the space $\mathcal L(\mathcal{l}^2, \mathbb{C})$, such that the sequence converges to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for every $x \in \mathcal l^2$. Is it true or not that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||f_n|| = 0$, where $||\cdot||$ is the operator norm?

Intuition tells me its true... here's why:

I want to say something along these lines, by defintion of convergence, we have that $\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $n>N$, we have that $|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon$. However, by definition of the operator norm, $||f_n|| \leq|f_n(x)|<\varepsilon.$ So with the same $N$, we have that that$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}||f_n|| = 0$

Is this correct or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: No. Let $\{e_n\}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis for $\ell^2$ and take $f_n(x) := \langle x,e_n\rangle$. This goes to zero pointwise (Riemann-Lebesgue lemma), but has norm 1 for all $n$. However, you can conclude that $\{\|f_n\|\}$ has to be a *bounded* sequence (uniform boundedness principle) if it converges to zero pointwise.

Comment: Thanks for this but we didn't cover the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma in class so I'm sure there's another way to justify that this is false, no?

Comment: Well, in this case you don't need it I guess. Here $\sum |f_n(x)|^2 = \|x\|^2$ by definition, so the $n^{th}$ term must go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

As Prahlad Vaidyanathan pointed out, this is false, a counterexample being the coordinate linear functionals $f_n(x) = x_n$. For each $x\in \ell^2$ we have $x_n\to 0$ due to $\sum |x_n|^2<\infty$. However, $\|f_n\|=1$ for all $n$.

The concept  of pointwise convergence that you are considering is precisely the [weak convergence on a Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)). (It becomes known as weak* convergence for general Banach spaces).